# JEditorPane Content Type for HTML Embedded Base64 Images

Tags: java, html, image, swing, jeditorpane

I am using JeditorPane and JEditorKit to display some HTML. The HTML is displaying correctly but the images show up as broken (they display properly in a browser). The image src is base64. I set the content type thus:

```
final JEditorPane ed=new JEditorPane();
ed.setContentType("text/html");
```

I'm guessing that because it contains both text and images, the content type is incorrect. If that is the case, what should it be set to? TIA.

** After Madushan Perera's reply**

```
final JEditorPane ed=new JEditorPane();
ed.setContentType("text/html");
ed.setEditable(false);
HTMLDocument html=(HTMLDocument) ed.getDocument();
html.putProperty("IgnoreCharsetDirective", new Boolean(true));
HTMLEditorKit htmle=(HTMLEditorKit) ed.getEditorKit();
try {
    htmle.insertHTML(html,html.getLength(),content,0,0,null);
} catch (BadLocationException | IOException e) {
    // Should not get here
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ed.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
          public void hyperlinkUpdate(final HyperlinkEvent pE) {
              if (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED == pE.getEventType()) {
                  String desc = pE.getDescription();
                  if (desc == null || !desc.startsWith("#")) return;
                  desc = desc.substring(1);
                  ed.scrollToReference(desc);
              }
          }
      });
ed.setCaretPosition(0);
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(ed,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
JPanel jp=new JPanel();
Dimension size=new Dimension(700,700);
jp.setPreferredSize(size);
jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
jp.add(scroll);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jp,title,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

'html' is the string containing the HTML. It was read from an html file type using IOUtils.toString. I'm probably going to have to develop an SCCE.

*Implementing CustomEditor*

```
        final JEditorPane ed=new JEditorPane();
        ed.setContentType("text/html");
        ed.setEditable(false);
        CustomToolKit htmle=new CustomToolKit();
        ed.setEditorKit(htmle);
        String content=readFile(fileName_+".html").replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
        content=content.replace("!!!!",VERSION.VERSION);
        ed.setText(content);
        ed.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(final HyperlinkEvent pE) {
                if (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED == pE.getEventType()) {
                    String desc = pE.getDescription();
                    if (desc == null || !desc.startsWith("#")) return;
                    desc = desc.substring(1);
                    ed.scrollToReference(desc);
                }
            }
        });
        ed.setCaretPosition(0);
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(ed,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JPanel jp=new JPanel();
        Dimension size=new Dimension(700,700);
        jp.setPreferredSize(size);
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jp.add(scroll);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,jp,title,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Now I get nothing. Obviously I did not properly implement your suggestion.

Comment: Swing's (default) HTML support does not extend to Base 64 encoded images.

Comment: In doing some debugging I believe that the custom editor is the problem. While the string being processed has hundreds of tags, the method ViewFactory.create is only called 4 times. The values of 'kind' were: html, body, p, content. The last is odd since there is no content tag. I ran my HTML through a verifier and it passed.

Comment: I figured out that 'content' is referring to the text between <p> tags, et al. It is just a coincidence that I chose 'content' as my variable name. In any case the bottom line is that although there are no exceptions or errors when running, there are also no more calls to "create" after that first content tag. I am trying to write an SSCCE but I may need to start a new thread since there are other problems with that.

Comment: After more debugging is it possible I am running into a problem with the length of the string? The entire string is about 32K characters. However, my reading says the max length of a string is 2^31 - 1.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like below :

```
    String imgsrc = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("your_package_name/image.png").toString();

    editor_pane.setContentType("text/html");
    editor_pane.setEditable(false);
    editor_pane.setText("<h3>Image Title</h3><img src='" + imgsrc + "' alt='img' name='img_name' width='100' height='100' /><br />");
```

**UPDATE :**

```
    String imgURL = "data:image/png;base64,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";

    String encodedImg = imgURL.split(",")[1];
    byte[] decodedImg = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedImg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Path destinationFile = Paths.get("C:\\your_path\\", "myImage.jpg");
    try {
        Path path = Files.write(destinationFile, decodedImg);
        editor_pane.setContentType("text/html");
        editor_pane.setEditable(false);
        editor_pane.setText("<h3>Image Title</h3><img src='" + path.toAbsolutePath().toUri() + "' alt='img_alt' width='150' height='150' /><br />");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

You have to create custom toolkit for the `JEditorPane` like below :

```
public class CustomToolKit extends HTMLEditorKit {

    private static HTMLFactory factory = null;

    @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new HTMLFactory() {

                @Override
                public View create(Element elem) {
                    AttributeSet attrs = elem.getAttributes();
                    Object elementName = attrs.getAttribute(AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute);
                    Object o = (elementName != null) ? null : attrs.getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
                    if (o instanceof HTML.Tag) {
                        HTML.Tag kind = (HTML.Tag) o;
                        if (kind == HTML.Tag.IMG) {
                            return new BASE64ImageView(elem);
                        }
                    }
                    return super.create(elem);
                }
            };
        }
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Then you have to override the `getImageURL()` of `javax.swing.text.html.ImageView` to support Base64 encoded images:

```
public class BASE64ImageView extends ImageView {

    private URL url;

    public BASE64ImageView(Element elmnt) {
        super(elmnt);
        populateImage();
    }

    private void populateImage() {
        Dictionary<URL, Image> cache = (Dictionary<URL, Image>) getDocument()
                .getProperty("imageCache");
        if (cache == null) {
            cache = new Hashtable<>();
            getDocument().putProperty("imageCache", cache);
        }

        URL src = getImageURL();
        cache.put(src, loadImage());

    }

    private Image loadImage() {
        String b64 = getBASE64Image();
        BufferedImage newImage = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
        try {
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64.getBytes()));
            newImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newImage;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getImageURL() {
        String src = (String) getElement().getAttributes()
                .getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
        if (isBase64Encoded(src)) {

            this.url = BASE64ImageView.class.getProtectionDomain()
                    .getCodeSource().getLocation();

            return this.url;
        }
        return super.getImageURL();
    }

    private boolean isBase64Encoded(String src) {
        return src != null && src.contains("base64,");
    }

    private String getBASE64Image() {
        String src = (String) getElement().getAttributes()
                .getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
        if (!isBase64Encoded(src)) {
            return null;
        }
        return src.substring(src.indexOf("base64,") + 7, src.length() - 1);
    }

}
```

Finally you can set your `CustomToolKit` to your `editorPane` :

```
        String imgURL = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA.........";
        editor_pane.setContentType("text/html");
        editor_pane.setEditable(false);
        CustomToolKit toolKit = new CustomToolKit();
        editor_pane.setEditorKit(toolKit);
        editor_pane.setText("<h1>Image Title</h1><img src='" + imgURL + "' alt='img_alt' width='150' height='150' /><br />");
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it is that simple. I've updated the OP with all my code but I am guessing from your reply the content type is not the problem.

Comment: Are you saying I have to decode into an external file then read it back in just to display it?  Is there no way to do it entirely in memory?

Comment: Yes, There is no way to get image uri instead of saving it to the disk. But alternatively you can implement custom editor to your jEditorpane as I mentioned in my `Update 2`.

Comment: Holy smokes. I had no idea it was that complicated. Is it possible to change my img src to simplify it? Only Java will be displaying it.

Comment: Yes , Instead of base64 encoded images you can use a normal image there. :)

Comment: Me, earlier: *"Swing's **(default)** HTML support does not extend to Base 64 encoded images."* Your edit: *"You have to create **custom toolkit** for the JEditorPane like below :"* ... nice work! :)

Comment: If you mean using an image file, I have never been able to get that to work in Java which is why I'm using base64 encoding. I'll have to think about what to do.

Comment: I'm trying your EditorKit extension but there are 2 problems. What is 'HTML.Attribute' and 'HTML.Tag'? They do not appear to be part of any library.

Comment: No It is not from any library. just import `javax.swing.text.html.HTML`

Comment: Thanks. Odd that my IDE didn't import it automatically like everything else. That is what threw me off.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion.  When I use your classes I get nothing output. I've update the OP.

Comment: In trying to create an SSCCE I found that if the html is in a literal string, the code works. I am accepting this solution. Ti problem apparently is related to reading the html from a jar file. I need to do more development of the SSCCE and will start a new thread if necessary.

Comment: How do you create a unique url for the image cache in the case of multiple base64 images?

Answer (score 0):

"Swing's (default) HTML support does not extend to Base 64 encoded images.", comment by Andrew Thompson,
is a gap in supported protocols of class `java.net.URL`. This may be filled by an additional URLStreamHandler for protocol "data".

```
/**
 * Stream handler for protocol "data"
 * @author Sam Ginrich
 *
*/
public class DataURLStreamHandler extends URLStreamHandler
{

    public DataURLStreamHandler()
    {
    }   

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL u) throws IOException
    {
        return new DataURLConnection(u);
    }

}
```

---

```
/**
 * URLConnection for protocol "data", decoding base64 URLs
 * 
 * @author Sam Ginrich
 *
 */
public class DataURLConnection extends URLConnection
{

    ByteArrayInputStream bis;

    protected DataURLConnection(final URL url)
    {
        super(url);
        bis = null;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream()
    {
        if (bis == null)
        {
            final String path = super.url.getPath(); // URL content, after "data:"
            final String[] parts = path.split(",");
            final String[] encoding = parts[0].split(";");
            if (encoding.length < 2 || !encoding[1].toLowerCase().contains("base64"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            final byte[] chars = Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1]);
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(chars);
        }
        return bis;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException
    {
    }

}
```

---

Integration of a single additional protocol was not meant by Java Runtime Design and so needs some Reflection

```
/**
 * Factory for DataURLStreamHandler
 * 
 * @author Sam Ginrich
 *
 */
public class DataURLStreamFactory implements URLStreamHandlerFactory
{
    URLStreamHandlerFactory oldFactory;
    Field fFactory;
    Field fHandlerLock;

    /**
     * To be called in a static code segment of a consumer class
     */
    public static void install()
    {
        new DataURLStreamFactory();
    }

    private DataURLStreamFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Class URL design does not foresee a set of specific factories,
            // adapt existing instance by reflection
            fFactory = URL.class.getDeclaredField("factory");
            fFactory.setAccessible(true);

            // Protection of URL.factory and URL.handlers
            fHandlerLock = URL.class.getDeclaredField("streamHandlerLock");
            fHandlerLock.setAccessible(true);

            URLStreamHandlerFactory current = (URLStreamHandlerFactory) fFactory.get(null);
            if (current != null && current instanceof DataURLStreamFactory)
            {
                // instance of DataURLStreamFactory already installed
                return;
            }
            oldFactory = current;
            URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(this);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            fFactory = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(final String protocol)
    {
        // Option 1, data protocol
        if ("data".equals(protocol))
        {
            return new DataURLStreamHandler();
        }
        else
        {
            URLStreamHandler res = null;
            try
            {
                // Option 2, protocols used by old factory
                if (oldFactory != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        res = oldFactory.createURLStreamHandler(protocol);
                    }
                    catch (final Exception mux)
                    {
                        res = null;
                    }
                }

                // Option 3, use built-in factory
                if (res == null)
                {
                    synchronized (fHandlerLock.get(null))
                    {
                        // URL.factory might be other than "this"
                        final URLStreamHandlerFactory current = (URLStreamHandlerFactory) fFactory.get(null);

                        // choose path of built-in factory
                        fFactory.set(null, null);
                        final Method gus = URL.class.getDeclaredMethod("getURLStreamHandler",
                                new Class<?>[] { String.class });
                        gus.setAccessible(true);
                        res = (URLStreamHandler) gus.invoke(null, protocol);
                        fFactory.set(null, current); // re-establish factory
                    }
                }
                return res;
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
};
```