# Display base64-encoded image

Tags: java, html, jtextpane

I have a problem with the integration of an image in a text/html JTextPane.
The JTextPane is initialized with the following text:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I insert text with:

```java
kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<b>" + string + "</b><br>" , 0, 0, HTML.Tag.B);
```

All the text inserted this way is displayed correctly, but when I tried inserting a base64-encoded image with:

```java
kit.insertHTML(doc,doc.getLength(), "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64Code + "\"/>", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.IMG);
```

I only got a placeholder image. When trying with a normal source path, it worked. However, getting the base64 code online and using that got me a placeholder image too, while the exact same code worked on w3school.com's HTML tryit editor.

Comment: Base64 string may contain characters like = that will break your HTML unless you encode them when building your HTML.  For example, = should be %3D

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I'm searching for a chart of such characters, do you already have one? Edit: Have found this (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), but there is no = mentioned there.

Comment: Just pass the base64 string thru java.net.URLEncoder.encode(base64Code, "UTF-8")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a [`JTextPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) sees an `<img>` tag, it will check if the image exists in a cache, and if not, it will try to read the image from the url. The html library used by `JTextPane` does not support base64 encoded image data in the `<img>` tag, so we will need to do it in a different way.

It turns out that we can manually add images to the image cache. This can be utilized to pick some otherwise invalid url and assign it an image.

---

Let's add the image to the cache and show it in a `JTextPane`!

First you want to convert the image into a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). This can be done using the [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class.

```
byte[] imgBytes = decodeBase64(base64Code);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));
```

Note that here we need the raw image bytes, not the base64 encoding. If you are reading the image from a file, you can pass a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to the `read` function instead of the input stream.

---

Now that we have the image as a `BufferedImage`, we can write a function that adds it to the cache.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static String saveImageToCache(JTextPane pane, BufferedImage img, String name) throws MalformedURLException {
    Dictionary cache = (Dictionary) pane.getDocument().getProperty("imageCache");
    if (cache == null) {
        // No cache exists, so create a new one.
        cache = new Hashtable();
        pane.getDocument().putProperty("imageCache", cache);
    }
    String url = "http:\\buffered/" + name;
    cache.put(new URL(url), img);
    return url;
}
```

Note that I suppress some warnings about type parameters on `Dictionary` and `Hashtable`. Normally this should be avoided, but in this case we are dealing with Swing nonsense in a way where it's ok to suppress the warnings.

This method essentially picks some invalid url and stores the image at that url.

Notice the `name` argument. This will be part of the url, and if you try to store an image to the cache with the same name as a previous image, this will replace that previous image. Avoid using crazy characters in this name, as `new Url(url)` may throw a [`MalformedURLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html) if it is not a valid url.

---

We can now use it with [`JTextPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html).

```
BufferedImage img = ...;

JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
pane.setContentType("text/html");

String url = saveImageToCache(pane, img, "image1");

pane.setText("<html><body><img src=\"" + url + "\"></body></html>");

JFrame frame = new JFrame("image test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
frame.setSize(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Note that you must call `setContentType` before adding the image to the cache, as the method clears the cache. Furthermore it is important that an image is added to the cache before `setText` is called, to ensure that images are added before swing needs it.

If the image in the cache is changed by using `saveImageToCache` with a previously known name, you will need to update the `JTextPane` in some way, such as calling `setText`.

---

If you have a lot of images, you might want to remove them from the cache when they are no longer needed, in order to avoid excessive memory usage. One way to do this would be to define a function as the one below, which removes the image from the cache.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
public static void removeImageFromCache(JTextPane pane, String name) throws MalformedURLException {
    Dictionary cache = (Dictionary) pane.getDocument().getProperty("imageCache");
    if (cache == null) {
        // There is no cache, so the image is not in the cache.
        return;
    }
    String url = "http:\\buffered/" + name;
    cache.remove(new URL(url));
}
```

You can also clear the cache by calling `setContentType` or by replacing the `JTextPane` with a new object. This works as the cache is stored in the `JTextPane`.

Comment: Excellent solution! It should work to continue with the base64-url, for it is unique and you don't loose persistency of the html content, which is the initial purpose of embedding an image.

Answer (score 0):

As the JTextPane can well manage pasting Images from Web-Urls, it also can manage the caching of Images. The actual problem is the fact that Java does not come with support of data URLs. As soon as they are supported, embedded images are displayed and cached.

Three things are required for a persistent solution:

- Data Stream Protocol Handler
- Data URL Connection
- Integration of the Protocol Handler with class `java.net.URL`

**EDIT**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78006445/9437799